# Python3: setup.py does not install package or subpackages

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I would like help regarding `setuptools` and `import`s. I have been unable to run `pip install .` and have `package` importable by any arbitrary python script like this

```py
import package
```

Here is an example file structure I have tried to play with

```
.
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── package
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __main__.py
        ├── package1
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── module1.py
        └── package2
            ├── __init__.py
            └── module2.py
```

Content of `setup.py`

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name="package",
      version="1.0.0",
      python_requires='>=3.8',
      package_dir={"package": "src"},
      packages=['package'])
```

Content of `src/package/__init__.py`

```py
from . import package1
from . import package2
```

Content of `src/package/__main__.py`

```py
import package2
from package2.module2 import function2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    function2()
    print("Hello from main")
```

Content of `src/package/package1/__init__.py`

```py
from . import module1
```

Content of `src/package/package1/module1.py`

```py
def function1():
    print("Hello from function1")
```

Content of `src/package/package2/__init__.py`

```py
from . import module2
```

Content of `src/package/package2/module2.py`

```py
import package1
from package1.module1 import function1
def function2():
    function1()
    print("Hello from function2")
```

If I run `__main__.py` with `python3 src/package` the output is

```
Hello from function1
Hello from function2
Hello from main
```

It works as I want it from `__main__`. Now, I want to install `package` so I can import with a simple `import package`.
I do this with `pip install .`

I then create a script in an arbitrary folder with this content

```py
import package
```

However, I get the error
`/bin/python3.10 /home/ubuntu/tmp/test.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/ubuntu/tmp/test.py", line 1, in <module> import package ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'`

My goal is to be able to run a script like this from anywhere and not have it error.

```py
import package
function2()
```

Output would be

```
Hello from function1
Hello from function2
```

What lines of code must change for `package` to be importable from any script, and why did it not work with the code and filestructure provided above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `{"package": "src"}` means "the src directory is the package", it would work if you had:

```
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── package1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module1.py
    ├── package2
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module2.py
```

But you have `package` inside `src` so you need to indicate the `root folder` for your packages with is the empty string of `package_dir`, like:

```
package_dir={"": "src"}
```

Then it starts to work:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel && unzip -l dist/package-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl 
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       46  2022-06-14 09:11   package/__init__.py
      127  2022-06-14 09:12   package/__main__.py
```

But you're missing the other package, so you either need to list them all:

```
packages=["package", "package.package1", "package.package2"]
```

Or make `setuptools` work for you:

```
packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="src")
```

In both cases your 3 packages are installed:

```
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       46  2022-06-14 09:11   package/__init__.py
      127  2022-06-14 09:12   package/__main__.py
       22  2022-06-14 09:12   package/package1/__init__.py
       51  2022-06-14 09:12   package/package1/module1.py
       22  2022-06-14 09:12   package/package2/__init__.py
      122  2022-06-14 09:12   package/package2/module2.py
```